# Why do we use one hot coding for the FSM Machine? why not binary coding to be used?

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to know why it is best to use grey coding or one hot rather than just binary coding.althiugh we would require more number of flip flops for its implementation.

Comment: This question is googable in seconds.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: First challenge the premise of the question : IS it best? Not always...

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, although one-hot encoding uses more FFs than binary encoding, it is much simpler to *decode* the states, and this often allows significantly higher performance (clock rate). It also maps particularly well onto most FPGA architectures, which usually have a 4 to 6-input LUT followed by a FF.

On the other hand, FPGAs also often have dedicated structures that make implementing binary counters efficient, too. So it really boils down to the nature of the specific FSM you want to implement. If it has a lot of "random" transitions among all the different states, one-hot will probably be preferred. If it is mostly long sequences of steps with little branching, then binary will be preferred.